# Rails 5.0.0.1: Why does match controller in my routes file not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    #get 'welcome/index'
    #get 'welcome/sample'
     match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', : via => :get 

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html


    root 'welcome#index'

end
```

The match controller section does not allow me to go to the route welcome/sample or welcome/index

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me but `: via` should be `:via`.
Also I would recommend you to use `get` instead of `match`. See [rails github guide](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bdd518343e3dfaae1dad123db2a55d25773fc278/guides/source/routing.md#http-verb-constraints) (thank you @ABPrime).

```
get ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
```